# On order page in action tab want to delete button

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, action

In the Sales>Order page on the right side, there is the drop-down option for Actions. In that actions tab, there is the delete option and I want to hide this option from that page. Anyone know how to hide this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi. In default magento there are no delete option exist for sales>order>Actions tab. I think it arrives from any third party extension. You have installed any third party extension?

Answer (score 0):

In the default Magento "Delete order" feature is not available. There will be some extension or custom code for this.

So follow this steps to find if any extension for this:

1. Go to Magento directory in app/code there will be directories local and community. Inside this directories check any delete order extension.
2. if an extension is there like company/deleteorder then go to app/etc/modules and edit XML file for that module for example company_deleteorder.xml. 
   And change the active tag to false.
3. Flush cache and check